# Android application crashes on starting an Activity with message 'FATAL EXCEPTION: Async #3'

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, android-cursorloader

I am trying to make an application where I need to generate a ListView with data retrieved from a SQLite database.

But as soon as an activity is initiated which does the above task, the application crashes.

Here's the activity code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class DisplayTasks extends ListActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
            String fromColumns[] = {TaskEntryDetails.TASK_SUMMARY};
            int toViews[] = {R.id.textView1};

            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, null, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one, or start a new one.
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        }


    private SQLiteCursorLoader loader;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private DbHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteOpenHelper db=null;

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    //New
    TaskEntry taskentry = new TaskEntry(DisplayTasks.this);
    dbHelper=taskentry.DbHelpermethod();

    db = dbHelper;
    String rawQuery = "SELECT " + TaskEntryDetails._ID + " , " + TaskEntryDetails.TASK_SUMMARY + " FROM " + TaskEntryDetails.TABLE_NAME;
    loader = new SQLiteCursorLoader(this, db, rawQuery, null);
    return(loader);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        adapter.changeCursor(null);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_display_tasks, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

And the logcat report contains:

```
03-07 19:38:12.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32626): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 19:38:12.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32626):    at com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLiteCursorLoader.buildCursor(SQLiteCursorLoader.java:54)
03-07 19:38:12.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32626):    at com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.AbstractCursorLoader.loadInBackground(AbstractCursorLoader.java:41)
03-07 19:38:12.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32626):    at com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.AbstractCursorLoader.loadInBackground(AbstractCursorLoader.java:1)
03-07 19:38:12.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32626):    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:301)
03-07 19:38:12.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32626):    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:68)
03-07 19:38:12.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32626):    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:56)
03-07 19:38:12.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32626):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-07 19:38:12.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32626):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-07 19:38:12.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32626):    ... 3 more
03-07 19:38:12.321: W/DropBoxManagerService(481): Dropping: data_app_crash (1407 > 0 bytes)
03-07 19:38:12.331: W/ActivityManager(481):   Force finishing activity com.example.theapp/.DisplayTasks
03-07 19:38:12.361: W/ActivityManager(481):   Force finishing activity com.example.theapp/.MainActivity
03-07 19:38:12.481: I/ActivityManager(481): Displayed com.example.theapp/.DisplayTasks: +219ms
03-07 19:38:14.381: I/Process(32626): Sending signal. PID: 32626 SIG: 9
03-07 19:38:14.391: I/ActivityManager(481): Process com.example.theapp (pid 32626) has died.
03-07 19:38:14.411: W/InputMethodManagerService(481): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 32626 uid 10083
```

Here's the code for TaskEntry.java

```
public static final String TAG = "TaskEntry";
private DbHelper dbHelper;

public TaskEntry(Context context){
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
}
public DbHelper DbHelpermethod() {
    return this.dbHelper();
}

// Inserting into Database
public void insertIntoDb(String summary) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TaskEntryDetails.TASK_SUMMARY, summary);

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    long newRowId;
    newRowId = db.insert(TaskEntryDetails.TABLE_NAME, TaskEntryDetails._ID, values);
}
```

and DbHelper.java:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TAG = "TaskEntry";
private static Context context;

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TaskEntryDetails.DB_NAME, null, TaskEntryDetails.DB_VERSION);
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s" + "(%s INT PRIMARY KEY, %s TEXT)", TaskEntryDetails.TABLE_NAME, TaskEntryDetails._ID,TaskEntryDetails.TASK_SUMMARY);

    Log.d(TAG, "Created database by name - " + TaskEntryDetails.DB_NAME);
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP IF EXISTS " + TaskEntryDetails.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

TaskEntryDetails.java:

```
public class TaskEntryDetails implements BaseColumns {
public static final String DB_NAME = "tasks_list.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tasks_list";
public static final String TASK_SUMMARY = "task_details";
}
```

I am currently using an open-source library 'CWAC-LoaderEX' to get a CursorLoader for the data in SQLite database.

I have successfully retrieved and displayed data from the same database into a ScrollView so hopefully the issue must not be with the database.

EDIT 1:

The code seems to crash with another message now..

```
03-08 20:37:10.031: D/libEGL(9969): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
03-08 20:37:10.071: D/libEGL(9969): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
03-08 20:37:10.091: D/libEGL(9969): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
03-08 20:37:10.141: D/OpenGLRenderer(9969): Enabling debug mode 0
03-08 20:37:12.411: D/AndroidRuntime(9969): Shutting down VM
03-08 20:37:12.411: W/dalvikvm(9969): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c28930)
03-08 20:37:12.421: E/AndroidRuntime(9969): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 20:37:12.421: E/AndroidRuntime(9969): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 20:37:12.421: E/AndroidRuntime(9969):     at com.example.theapp.DisplayTasks.onLoadFinished(DisplayTasks.java:83)
03-08 20:37:12.421: E/AndroidRuntime(9969):     at com.example.theapp.DisplayTasks.onLoadFinished(DisplayTasks.java:1)
03-08 20:37:12.421: E/AndroidRuntime(9969):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:483)
03-08 20:37:12.421: E/AndroidRuntime(9969):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:451)
03-08 20:37:12.421: E/AndroidRuntime(9969):     at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:143)
03-08 20:37:12.421: E/AndroidRuntime(9969):     at com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.AbstractCursorLoader.deliverResult(AbstractCursorLoader.java:71)
03-08 20:37:12.421: E/AndroidRuntime(9969):     at com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.AbstractCursorLoader.deliverResult(AbstractCursorLoader.java:1)
```

Comment: why you comment `//dbHelper = new TaskEntry.DbHelper();` line ? you are getting error because `db` or `dbHelper` instance is `null`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I actually tried doing that, but eclipse refuses me to do that. It says 'No enclosing instance of type TaskEntry is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type TaskEntry.'

Comment: if `TaskEntry` is class and `DbHelper()` is non static method then use `dbHelper=new TaskEntry().DbHelper()` instead of `dbHelper = new TaskEntry.DbHelper();` and if `DbHelper()`  is static method then use `dbHelper=TaskEntry.DbHelper()`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Looks like I can't figure out this way. So am posting the code for TaskEntry.java here:

[link](http://pastie.org/6412614)

Comment: ok show TaskEntry.java class code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have added it in my main post.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Eclipse is giving an error on the line:
    taskentryDetails.new TaskEntry(DisplayTasks.this).DbHelpermethod();

It says 'TaskEntryDetails.TaskEntry cannot be resolved to a type'.
I may add that TaskEntry is not nested inside TaskEntryDetails. Don't know if that helps.

Comment: best way is create separate class files for TaskEntry and DbHelper as TaskEntry.java,DbHelper.java

Comment: ok change your class as http://pastebin.com/sx1BSAjQ

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Still doesn't work..TaskEntry.java's DbHelperMehtod() says 'The method dbHelper() is undefined for the type TaskEntry' on the line 'return this.dbHelper;'. Changing it to 'DbHelpermethod()'.. OR 'creating method 'dbHelper() - an empty one' on Eclipse's recommendation causes the same crash.

Comment: ok edit your latest all code in question

Comment: use `return this.dbHelper;` instead of `return this.dbHelper();` inside DbHelpermethod() method dear

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Thanks.. though now I seem to have run into another issue..

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Thanks..!! Though I can only thank you for the same as my reputation doesn't allow me to 'appreciate' your comments..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was initially with correctly initializing the database. It should have been done as:

The class TaskEntry ( in TaskEntry.java )

```
public class TaskEntry {

public static final String TAG = "TaskEntry";
private DbHelper dbHelper;

public TaskEntry(Context context){
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
}
public DbHelper DbHelpermethod() {
    return this.dbHelper;
}
...}
```

Also, the LoaderManager was not implemented correctly..

After the onCreateLoader (which was rather fine).. a cursor is initialized, which doesn't get passed into the onLoadFinished and onLoaderReset calls. They receive the old adapter here which is initialized with 'null' as cursor value.
Ref:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, null, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
```

This is fixed by replacing:

```
adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
```

in onLoadFinished and

```
adapter.changeCursor(null);
```

in onLoaderReset in the DisplayTasks.java activity by:

```
((SimpleCursorAdapter)this.getListAdapter()).changeCursor(cursor);
```

and..

```
((SimpleCursorAdapter)this.getListAdapter()).changeCursor(null);
```

repectively..

Answer (score 1):

```
03-07 19:38:12.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32626): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 19:38:12.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32626):    at com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLiteCursorLoader.buildCursor(SQLiteCursorLoader.java:54)
```

Assuming that you are working off of the latest code, that line is the `return` statement in:

```
  @Override
  protected Cursor buildCursor() {
    return(db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(rawQuery, args));
  }
```

Which means that either `db` is `null` (because you passed in a `null` `SQLiteOpenHelper` to the `SQLiteCursorLoader` constructor) or because `db.getReadableDatabase()` is `null` (which should not happen).

And, since I fail to see where you create a `SQLiteOpenHelper` object in your above code, that is likely to be the source of your difficulty.

Bear in mind that when using open source libraries that they are *open source*, meaning that you can go read the code associated with them, to help you track down issues like these.

Comment: It seems that I am unable to initialize a database helper object here. I have added the code of the file that takes care of it in the post.

Also, tell me if using SQLiteOpenHelper here is fine.

Comment: @AdityaBhardwaj: "It seems that I am unable to initialize a database helper object here" -- yes, you can, such as in `onCreate()` of your activity. "I have added the code of the file that takes care of it in the post" -- no you have not, as the only code that seems to create one is commented out and therefore cannot be executed. "Also, tell me if using SQLiteOpenHelper here is fine" -- you should hold onto your `SQLiteOpenHelper` somewhere, as you will likely need it later.

Comment: Thanks.. I figured out my problem..:-)
Though my reputation doesn't allow me to vote up for your answer..